# Using subprocess to find out when a process ends

Tags: python, windows, process, build-automation, fork

I wish to sequentially run some c scripts that fork their own processes (in a new command line window) and give the `"Press any key to continue..."` when they are completed.  Technically, it is a special compiler.  It pops up with acommand line window and tells me whether the compile was successful or not.  But that command line window forks new processes to compile, which are making this return 0 before it should..

My first attempt at this was

```
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    process.wait()
```

while iterating over each file.  Unfortunately, this does not wait for the "Press any key to continue..." and blows up in my face.  It seems that the `wait()` call is passed when an internal process is completed (which I have no access to).

How can I, instead, wait for "Press any key to continue..."?  It's also printing some other information before the press any key to continue line..

Currently, this is what my code is:

```
            process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            completed = False
            while not completed:
                if process.poll() is not None:
                    completed = True

            print "communicating"
            process.communicate("k")
            print "communicated"
```

Comment: The new code is nonsensical: you're busy-waiting for the process to die (wait() would do the same, only without overheating your CPU) and then trying to communicate with a dead process!

If the script you're launching forks a new process in the background and then returns immediatelly, there's not much you can do.  You'd have to get the pid of the grandchild process and then do an os.wait() on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subprocess.poll` to check the status without blocking, and `subprocess.communicate` to send information to the subprocess.

Comment: If it's giving me "Press any key to continue..." i thought it hadn't returned any value yet?  Would this not make subprocess.poll kind of useless?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't seem to be waiting for it to print "Press any key to continue..."

Comment: Try just using communicate - of course this assumes that `stdout` and `stdin` have been tied to the `subprocess.PIPE`, so you'll need to change it to `.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: I've updated the question with what I have.  It seems to lock at the communicate() command.  I have also tried it without an argument to try to get the stdout from it, but no dice.